# Date set in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ssh

I have some problems with ntpd sync on servers. Unless we resolve this issue I have written script to set date on servers manually for those who are not in sync.

For this I have taken one reference machine and I am catching current date of that machine and trying to set it on all other machines.

I'm using following command in script

```
ssh -i /mnt/keys/g.pem -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$IP 'date --set="$ref_date"'
```

but when command runs it set wrong date.

```
e.g ref_date=Sat Sep 24 06:52:17 UTC 2016
```

when I echo above command it shows following line

```
ssh -i /mnt/keys/g.pem -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@xx.xx.xx.xx 'date --set="Sat Sep 24 06:52:17 UTC 2016"'
```

but when same command actually runs it gives following output

```
ssh -i /mnt/keys/g.pem -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@xx.xx.xx.xx 'date --set="Sat Sep 24 06:52:17 UTC 2016"'

Sat Sep 24 00:00:00 UTC 2016
```

Note: I have replaced $IP with xx.xx.xx.xx in above outputs.

Kindly provide solution to this.

Comment: What do you get if you try `'date --date="Sat Sep 24 06:52:17 UTC 2016"'` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
ssh -i /mnt/keys/g.pem -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$IP "date --set=\"$ref_date\""
```

See: [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)